# duplicate entry while using push on array

Tags: reactjs, directus

The collaborators contain 3 data already and I am trying to push a user which should come first. I am baffled while I tried to use console.log(), I am getting 3 response values instead one. As illustrated below; it referenced to the line 25 and it printed trice.
However, when I pushed to collaborator, I am expecting a value but I got two  data values pushed to collaborator. I just want one. I have spent several hours trying to figure what I have done wrongly. Please, I don't know how, that is why I posted here.

```
const resData = async() => {
      const res = await directus.users.me.read()
      const result = res.data
      console.log(result)
      collaborators.push(result)
      }
      resData()
```

Comment: what does  directus.users.me.read() do

Comment: Please give us some more code so we can help you. You can use a http://codesandbox.io/

Comment: directus.users.me.read()  - read the current user that is logged in. A single user with all details as listed in console.log()

Comment: @BartKrakowski I would have loved to do so, but the code is a bit complex because directus setting etc.  It is much clear from question, I am reading the current user through the directus.users.me.read()  and push it to the collaborator array of the same objects

Answer (score 1):

I finally solved it by using useEffect.

```
useEffect(() => {
   const resData = async() => {
  const res = await directus.users.me.read()
  const result = await res.data
  collaborators.unshift(result)
  }
  resData()
},[collaborators])
```